# iOS How to scroll and resize at the same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I want to emulate the iOS 9 music app.
When you scroll up or down, I would like the header part to expand/collapse as the table is scrolled.

I've tried tweaking in `scrollViewDidScroll`, but I can't get it to bounce like the music app.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to check the offset of the scrolling and change the frame and x and y according to it... How much the frame size you increase decrease the x and y coordinates accordingly .

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

CGFloat yOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y/2 + 32;

CGRect frame = coverImage.frame;

    frame.size.height = MAX(150 - yOffset, 150);
    frame.size.width = MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH - yOffset, SCREEN_WIDTH);
    frame.origin.x = SCREEN_WIDTH/2 - frame.size.width/2;
    frame.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y + 64;
    coverImage.frame = frame;

    frame.origin.x = SCREEN_WIDTH/2 - 20;
    frame.origin.y = 0 - yOffset;
    frame.size.width = 40;
    frame.size.height = 40;
    loadingIcon.frame = frame;
    frame.origin.y = 0 - yOffset + 30;
    frame.origin.x = SCREEN_WIDTH/2 - 50;
    frame.size.width = 180;
    label.frame = frame;
    yOffset = 0;
    NSLog(@"YOFFSET : %f | Scroll offset : %f", yOffset, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
```

}

Hope This will help you in your problem.